# iOS back gesture close keyboard

Tags: ios, swift3

I would like to close the keyboard on back swipe.

Here is main part of the code

```
class ChatDetailController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    ....

    @IBOutlet weak var tvMsg: UITextView!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ChatDetailController.dismissKeyboard), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

    }

    func dismissKeyboard() {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

}
```

So as I start doing `back swipe` ie from left to right, the dismissKeyboard is being called but is not hiding the keyboard. Anything I am missing ?

Comment: use tvMsg.resignFirstResponder()

Comment: I have tried that as well but no luck :/

Comment: Surprisingly, your code is working fine in my side. How are you sure that your keyboard isn't being hidden? Is your keyboard automatically open when you re-visit your `ChatDetailController`?

Comment: What I ideally want to do it when the user starts back swipe gesture the keyboard must close. At the moment the keyboard is visible

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
func dismissKeyboard() {
        self.tvMsg.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you. I have tried that as well but no luck :/ Wondering if I am missing something

Comment: it is automatically being called as part of notification observer.

Comment: @sujithvm yes you are right but you can be sure that you are missing something, can you post more code?

Answer (score 0):

You can close the keyboard without knowing which ui element is the first responder like this:

```
UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
```